# Symfony 4 Single-Text DateTime Widget no longer accepting yyyy-MM-dd string

Tags: forms, datetime, symfony4

I'm sending a POST with the string 1980-01-02 as birth.

My controller is verifying it using a form with this config.

```
  ->add('birth', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'widget' => 'single_text', // so the API can send '2012-12-30'
                'attr' => ['date-widget' => 'single_text', 'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd']
            ));
```

This code was working on SF3, and maybe even on SF 4.1

Now I'm getting this error. `Unable to reverse value for property path "birth": The date "1980-01-02" is not a valid date.`

Any idea how to solve it?
Cheers

Comment: Not working Fabien, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was using DateTimeType instead DateType.
Also I can just use this options

```
           'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => true
```